# Python Optimization by Multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization

I am trying to optimize my Jupiter python script by the package called concurrent.futures.

I know the Jupiter has a mechanism to generate 4 engines to speed up, but when I use Task Manager and Resource Monitor to check the CPU status, CPUs' total utilization could be more than 25%, but just about 35%. And some CPUs could be used jumping to 100% suddenly.

After involving the concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor and concurrent.futures.as_complete, the total processing time become longer, the utilization rate becomes more stable but no one could be over 50%. It seems there is a lock to limit the CPUs utilization in this package, but I cannot find any relates.

Has does anyone ideas or experiences on this? Thank you so much for any pieces of advice.

Comment: Without you adding more details on what you are trying to do it is hard to answer. Meanwhile, just try using "ProcessPoolExecutor" instead of "ThreadPoolExecutor".  Your data-sets will be naively copied to all worker process, and if it is big, the overhead might be to great - but it should fix the problem of idle CPU's (if your calculations are actually CPU intensive, and not stalled on I/O requirements).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, it s CPU intensive.I will check the difference of ProcessPollExecutor and ThreadPoolExecutor, thank you so much.

Comment: "It seems there is a lock to limit the CPUs utilization" Yes, it's the GIL. You cannot speed up a CPU-intensive application in Python with threads, because of this. It basically prevents two threads of the same process from executing at the same time. You'll need to switch to multiprocessing instead.

Comment: @Rightleg it seems the concurrent package has no problem with the GIL, since no matter how many the thread created, there will be the same number of GILs.

Comment: @CarlZheng I'm not sure I understood. There's one GIL for each process, so multiprocessing will alow you to use more than one CPU. On the other hand, the GIL makes it so that two threads from the same process cannot run simultaneously - that is, they cannot both be performing CPU-bound operations, but if one is executing blocking I/O operations, the other will not be blocked.

Comment: @Rightleg "ProcessPoolExecutor uses the multiprocessing module, which allows it to side-step the Global Interpreter Lock but also means that only picklable objects can be executed and returned." This is quoted from https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor